# Smarty - How to make functions?

Tags: php, class, function, smarty

I have tried making a function which I can run in the .tpl files.

I included a class `Templates`:

```
<?php

class Templates {
    function getTemplate($template, $gameid) {
        echo "test";
    }
}

?>
```

Then I put this into the PHP page.

```
//Create a template object
$templates = new Templates();
$tpl->assign("template", $templates);
```

And then I try calling the function in the `tpl file`:

`{$template->get('header',1)}`

But I just get a blank page when I try this.

Any ideas how to actually do this?

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo introduced when uploading your question, but your PHP function is called `getTemplate` whereas your Smarty code calls a non-existent function called `get`.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look through the [documentation on Smarty Plugins](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.tpl). These allow you to register your own functions which can be used just like the built-in tags and modifiers, or even custom sources of template data for use with the `{include}` function.

Your example is too stripped-down to guess what you actually want to achieve, so feel free to post a follow-up question if you can't see a way of achieving your specific goal.